# Reactjs not updating the new value of product_number

Tags: reactjs

Reactjs not updating the new value of  product_number. I knew that similar question has been asked but am having hard time trying to resolve this.

The **Reactjs** code below displays provisions records from the arrays.
Now I need to update and replace the value the **product_number** from **001**  to **006**.

To this effect, I  have added an update button which fetch the **product_number** from the Axios Call.

My problem is that **product_number** is not updated with **006**  when the button is clicked.

**Here is the json response of Axios Call for product_number updates**

product_number.json

```
[{"product_number":"006"}]
```

**Here is the  code**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';


class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({


      data: [
{"provision_id":"1","provision":"Milk","category":[{"category_id":"1","category_price":"100 USD","product":[{"product_id":"1","product_number":"001"}]  }]}
],

    });
  }

// Get and update New Product number of Milk

 handleNewProductNumber(prod_id) {
alert(prod_id);
    const prod_data = {
      prod_id: prod_id};
    axios
      .get("http://localhost/provision/product_number.json", { prod_data })
      .then(response => {
        const newData = this.state.data.map(store => {

//if (product.product_id  !== prod_id) return product;
return {
  ...store, 
  product: store.product.map(
    product => {
      if (product.product_id !== prod_id) return product
      return { ...product, product_number: response.data[0].product_number }
    }
  )
};


        });

 this.setState(state => ({
          data: newData
        }));
console.log(response.data[0].category_price);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          <ul>


{this.state.data.map((store) => {

 return (
 <div key={store.provision_id}>
<div><h1>Provision Store</h1> <br />
<b> Product: </b>{store.provision} 

</div>



 {store.category && store.category.map((cat) => {

          return (
            <div key={cat.category_id}>
              <div><b>Prices:</b> {cat.category_price}






</div>
{cat.product && cat.product.map((prod) => <div key={prod.product_id}>
<b>Product Number:</b> #{prod.product_number}

 <br />
                <input
                  type="button"
                  value="Get & Update New Product Number"
                  onClick={() => this.handleNewProductNumber(prod.product_id)}
                />

</div>)}


              </div>
          )
        })}

</div>
)

 })}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

**Updated Section using map function**

```
    return {
      ...store, 
      category: store.category.map(
 product: store.product.map(
        product => {
          if (product.product_id !== prod_id) return product
          return { ...product, product_number: response.data[0].product_number }
        })

 })
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the same of the other question, you have an array of object, with inside another array of objects, in your state:

```
data: [
  {
    "provision_id": "1",
    "provision": "Milk",
    "category": [
      {
        "category_id": "1",
        "category_price": "100 USD",
        "product": [
          {
            "product_id": "1",
            "product_number": "001"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

To update the inner level, you have to traverse all the state tree:

```
return {
  ...store, 
  category: [{
    ...store.category,
    product: [{
       ...store.category[0].product,
       product_number: response.data[0].product_number
    }]
  }]
};
```

### Edit after... well, your edit

Your updated piece of code isn't valid syntax:

```
return {
  ...store, 
  category: store.category.map(
    product: store.product.map(
      product => {
        if (product.product_id !== prod_id) return product
        return { ...product, product_number: response.data[0].product_number }
      }
    )
  })
};
```

The first `store.category.map` call takes a function which will be called with a single category as an argument.

You have to spread the `category` prior to shadow the `product` property:

```
return {
  ...store, 
  category: store.category.map(
    category => ({
      ...category,
      product: category.product.map(
        product => {
          if (product.product_id !== prod_id) return product
          return { ...product, product_number: response.data[0].product_number }
        }
      )
    })
  )
};
```

Comment: Sir  0xc14m1z, your solution was great. it  works fine. please Sir, i prefer using your second option which makes use of map function. i tried implementing that following your previous solution but cannot get it to work. please can you see the updated section of my code to see what am doing wrong. between thanks for help so far

Comment: Sir 0xc14m1z., please can you help me with my new question on stacoverflow. Thanks    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324846/reactjs-cannot-get-json-data-via-mapping-function/54325841?noredirect=1#comment95479578_54325841